# FullCalendar doesn't work in laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, fullcalendar

I'm trying to set up fullCalendar in the laravel framework and for some reason it doesn't work.

I've made a separate prototype (no framework, just an index.html file) and when I copy that code, it suddenly doesn't work anymore...
I'm getting a `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).fullCalendar is not a function` error.

Can anyone tell me what I did wrong?

laravel:
app.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="<!DOCTYPE html">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <title>Larabase</title>

    <script src="{{ asset('bower/jquery/dist/jquery.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('bower/moment/moment.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('bower/moment/locale/nl.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('bower/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('bower/fullcalendar/dist/lang/nl.js') }}"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bower/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.css') }}"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bower/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.print.css') }}"/>


    @stack('scripts_head_before')

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}">
    {{-- Font Awesome --}}
    {{--<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">--}}

    @stack('scripts_head_after')

</head>

<body>

@include('partials.nav')

<div class="container" style="margin-top: 30px;">

    @include('partials.alert')

    @yield('content')

</div><!-- /.container -->

@stack('scripts_footer_before')

<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
================================================== -->
<!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
{!! HTML::script('js/global.js') !!}

@stack('scripts_footer_after')



</body>
</html>
```

laravel: home.blade.php

```
@extends('app')

@section('content')

    <div id='calendar'></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var events = [

            {
                title: 'Meeting',
                start: '2016-01-12T10:30:00',
                end: '2016-01-12T11:30:00'
            },
            {
                title: 'Meeting',
                start: '2016-01-12T11:30:00',
                end: '2016-01-12T12:30:00'
            },
            {
                title: 'Meeting',
                start: '2016-01-12T12:30:00',
                end: '2016-01-12T13:30:00'
            }
        ];

        $(document).ready(function () {

            // page is now ready, initialize the calendar...

            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                // put your options and callbacks here
                lang: 'nl',
                eventLimit: true,
                weekends: true,
                firstDay: 1,
                weekNumbers: true,
                businessHours: {
                    start: '10:00', // a start time (10am in this example)
                    end: '18:00', // an end time (6pm in this example)

                    dow: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
                    // days of week. an array of zero-based day of week integers (0=Sunday)
                    // (Monday-Thursday in this example)
                },
                events,
                dayClick: function (date, jsEvent, view) {

                    alert('Clicked on: ' + date.format());

                    alert('Coordinates: ' + jsEvent.pageX + ',' + jsEvent.pageY);

                    alert('Current view: ' + view.name);

                    // change the day's background color just for fun
                    $(this).css('background-color', 'red');

                },
                eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {

//                alert('Event: ' + calEvent.title);
//                alert('Coordinates: ' + jsEvent.pageX + ',' + jsEvent.pageY);
//                alert('View: ' + view.name);

                    console.log('event', calEvent);
                    console.log('jsEvent', jsEvent);
                    console.log('View', view);

                    // change the border color just for fun
                    $(this).css('border-color', 'red');
                }
            });
        });

    </script>

@stop
```

index.html prototype (that works):

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Fullcalendar prototype</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='bower_components/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.css'/>
    <script src='bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script src='bower_components/moment/min/moment.min.js'></script>
    <script src='bower_components/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.js'></script>
    <script src='bower_components/fullcalendar/dist/lang/nl.js'></script>
    <script src='bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Fullcalendar prototype&nbsp;
    <button id="addbutton" class="btn btn-default">+</button>
</h1>
<div id='calendar'></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var events = [

        {
            title: 'Meeting',
            start: '2016-01-12T10:30:00',
            end: '2016-01-12T11:30:00'
        },
        {
            title: 'Meeting',
            start: '2016-01-12T11:30:00',
            end: '2016-01-12T12:30:00'
        },
        {
            title: 'Meeting',
            start: '2016-01-12T12:30:00',
            end: '2016-01-12T13:30:00'
        }
    ];

    $(document).ready(function () {

        // page is now ready, initialize the calendar...

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            // put your options and callbacks here
            lang: 'nl',
            eventLimit: true,
            weekends: true,
            firstDay: 1,
            weekNumbers: true,
            businessHours: {
                start: '10:00', // a start time (10am in this example)
                end: '18:00', // an end time (6pm in this example)

                dow: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
                // days of week. an array of zero-based day of week integers (0=Sunday)
                // (Monday-Thursday in this example)
            },
            events,
            dayClick: function (date, jsEvent, view) {

                alert('Clicked on: ' + date.format());

                alert('Coordinates: ' + jsEvent.pageX + ',' + jsEvent.pageY);

                alert('Current view: ' + view.name);

                // change the day's background color just for fun
                $(this).css('background-color', 'red');

            },
            eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {

//                alert('Event: ' + calEvent.title);
//                alert('Coordinates: ' + jsEvent.pageX + ',' + jsEvent.pageY);
//                alert('View: ' + view.name);

                console.log('event', calEvent);
                console.log('jsEvent', jsEvent);
                console.log('View', view);

                // change the border color just for fun
                $(this).css('border-color', 'red');
            }
        });
    });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Write your code as below:-

**app.blade.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="<!DOCTYPE html">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <title>Larabase</title>

    <script src="{{ asset('bower/jquery/dist/jquery.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('bower/moment/moment.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('bower/moment/locale/nl.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('bower/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('bower/fullcalendar/dist/lang/nl.js') }}"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bower/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.css') }}"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bower/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.print.css') }}"/>


    @stack('scripts_head_before')

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}">
    {{-- Font Awesome --}}
    {{--<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">--}}

    @stack('scripts_head_after')

</head>

<body>

@include('partials.nav')

<div class="container" style="margin-top: 30px;">

    @include('partials.alert')

    @yield('content')

</div><!-- /.container -->

@stack('scripts_footer_before')

<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
================================================== -->
<!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
{!! HTML::script('js/global.js') !!}

@stack('scripts_footer_after')

// ADD another yield section here.
@yield('external_script')
</body>
</html>
```

**home.blade.php**

```
@extends('app')

@section('content')
     <!-- Add only div here -->
    <div id='calendar'></div>    
@stop

@section('external_script')
 <!-- Here is your script-->
<script type="text/javascript">
        var events = [

            {
                title: 'Meeting',
                start: '2016-01-12T10:30:00',
                end: '2016-01-12T11:30:00'
            },
            {
                title: 'Meeting',
                start: '2016-01-12T11:30:00',
                end: '2016-01-12T12:30:00'
            },
            {
                title: 'Meeting',
                start: '2016-01-12T12:30:00',
                end: '2016-01-12T13:30:00'
            }
        ];

        $(document).ready(function () {

            // page is now ready, initialize the calendar...

            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                // put your options and callbacks here
                lang: 'nl',
                eventLimit: true,
                weekends: true,
                firstDay: 1,
                weekNumbers: true,
                businessHours: {
                    start: '10:00', // a start time (10am in this example)
                    end: '18:00', // an end time (6pm in this example)

                    dow: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
                    // days of week. an array of zero-based day of week integers (0=Sunday)
                    // (Monday-Thursday in this example)
                },
                events,
                dayClick: function (date, jsEvent, view) {

                    alert('Clicked on: ' + date.format());

                    alert('Coordinates: ' + jsEvent.pageX + ',' + jsEvent.pageY);

                    alert('Current view: ' + view.name);

                    // change the day's background color just for fun
                    $(this).css('background-color', 'red');

                },
                eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {

//                alert('Event: ' + calEvent.title);
//                alert('Coordinates: ' + jsEvent.pageX + ',' + jsEvent.pageY);
//                alert('View: ' + view.name);

                    console.log('event', calEvent);
                    console.log('jsEvent', jsEvent);
                    console.log('View', view);

                    // change the border color just for fun
                    $(this).css('border-color', 'red');
                }
            });
        });

    </script>

@stop
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: This produces the exact same error, it just moves the problem I guess :P

Comment: Check your page source. Are all js  loaded or not? Also check your calender JS.

Comment: Yeap, it's all loaded, we found our problem tho.
One of the other developers added jquery with elixer, even though I've already loaded it this way, making it overwrite jquery and deleting all the jquery 'addons'.
Glad we found this, since it otherwise would've meant we would've stared at these 2 files for eternity I guess :P
But still thanks for you help!